# How can I use a bash alias at the end of an alias?

Tags: bash, alias

Is it possible to use an alias at the end of a command which uses an alias.
The full command would be:

```
kubectl delete pod nginx --grace-period=0 --force
```

These are my aliases:

```
alias k=kubectl
alias gpf="--grace-period=0 --force"
```

I want to combine both aliases to something like this:

```
k delete pod nginx gpf
```

Comment: Not in bash. zsh has a feature that's like this, but bash does not.

Comment: ...mind you, _in bash_, you could write a _function_ called `k` that acts like your alias, but also substitutes `gpf` with your desired list of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias is not a macro; it substitutes a command. `--grace-period=0` is not a command, and "compositions of aliases" would not work.

In addition, both of your commands don't define aliases. An alias is defined by

```
alias NAME='command to execute'
```

You are missing the `alias` keyword. Your definitions of `gpf` and `k` hence don't define aliases, but shell variables.

Still, your definition of `gpf` can be useful, because you can use it in i.e.

```
kubectl $gpf
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shell function has exactly the behavior you're asking for:

```
k() {
  local -a args=( kubectl )               # initialize argument list to "kubectl"
  for arg do                              # iterate over each funtion argument
    if [[ $arg = gpf ]]; then             # if that argument is "gpf"...
      args+=( --grace-period=0 --force )  # ...append the specific arguments we want
    else
      args+=( "$arg" )                    # otherwise, just append what we were given
    fi
  done
  "${args[@]}"                            # then run our list as a command.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

k delete pod nginx gpf --> this actually works but it throws an error.

If you note carefully, the pod deletion doesn't take much time.

the error says there is no pod called "gpf", not sure kubectl assumes gpf is a pod when it has already substituted the value.